# Elasticsearch Error Failed to create blob container

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to restore a snapshot to elasticsearch.
and as the first step need to create a repository.

when trying to execute

```
PUT /_snapshot/nuwan-backup
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "/mnt/nfs/esbackup/"
  }
}
```

Got following error

> "reason": "failed to create blob container"

Environment:
Elasticsearch v6.3.0, 3 node cluster is used and mounted to a shared folder.

Comment: are you sure that the elasticsearch user has grant to open /mnt/nfs/esbackup/ path? please execute chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch  /mnt/nfs/esbackup/  and try again

Comment: Thanks @Lupanoide the I tried your tip and didn't work. But managed to fix it by giving access at the server end, not at the client end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fix was to add elasticuser folder as the owner at source server not at the client. I was trying to execute chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /mnt/nfs/esbackup/ on client server which didn't succeed.

chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /esbackup/

Comment: or use command `sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /path/to/esbackup`